# how to load the language file in plugin?

Tags: plugins, customization, theme-development, multi-language

I'm unable to load the plugin's locale file *(.mo)*. I did all the procedues described in the http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin but its not working. If I the lang string to the wordpress default `wp-content/language/de_De.mo` file then its show the correct translated string. but not loading the data from my plugin folder :(

**EDIT:**

```
$plugin_dir = basename(dirname(__FILE__)) ."/lang/";
load_plugin_textdomain( 'tboy_displayTimeZone', null, $plugin_dir );
```

Answer (score 2):

"All procedures" is not very descriptive. :)

Are you calling `load_plugin_textdomain()` function? Had you set domain in your plugin's strings?

There is also relevant section here: [I18n for theme and plugin developers](http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers#I18n_for_theme_and_plugin_developers)

Comment: Yes I did everything

Comment: hmmm... what is your .mo file named exactly?

Comment: tboy_displayTimeZone.de_De.mo and tboy_displayTimeZone-de_De.mo I tried both.. :(

Comment: What does `load_textdomain( $domain, $mofile )` returns with your values for domain and path to .mo file? Boolean true/false.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if the plugin's unique name  is described in the translation keywords terms.
For example in this code:

```
echo = __('Word', 'your-plugin-unique-name');
```

The unique name is "your-plugin-unique-name". You should add this on load function:

```
load_plugin_textdomain( 'your-plugin-unique-name', null, $plugin_dir );
```

And also has it in your .MO file's name: 'your-plugin-unique-name-de_DE.mo'

It will work.